# how to give request uri to access http put method without using apex class in workbench and postman

Tags: rest-api, rest, workbench

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQJj1.png)

[image]

[image]

Put Method is Not working for any Requests whereas all Methods are Working Good can anyone Please guide me for the Answer

Comment: what you are trying to do ? are you trying to create new record ? you can't add @httpput notation in request body . you may need to create a service that accept the httpput notation

Comment: What is the use of PUT method on that url? I could not find that in REST Api guide. In fact i did not find any standard salesforce url using PUT method ( note : my search was limited to REST Api Developer guide).

Comment: @Ratan, Actually i am trying to update the using put method in rest api and first, just i check httpput notation if it will work or not. Later i removed this.

Comment: And as @Ratan said, you don't need @httpput in the request body. And my small hit and trial says `url : '/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/{SOBJ-NAME}/ with POST method and { "name" : "testname"}` will help you insert a new record;                  `url : '/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/{SOBJ-NAME}/{RecID}  with PATCH method and {"filed":"newVAlue"}` will update the record

Comment: @Saumya Ranjan Satapathy, 
Yes, you are right. we can also use patch method to update the records.
But what is use of Put method in Rest api?

Comment: @KSKumar It is there in workbench, so that if you write a new service method with @-httpput on top, you should be able to test it without client code. But as  PUT method is not supported by standard salesforce rest urls, you can not use that while invoking a standard one.

Comment: @Saumya Ranjan Satapathy,  please understand my question.
what my question is, can we able to do update operation using put method(Do not use patch method).
do not consider http put annotation. I uploaded wrong image.
please check the image which loaded again.

Comment: @KSKumar My bad if I misunderstood your question. But all I understand is while using some services we have to follow the service providers documentation. So now as in your case a standard salesforce given url is showing 'Method Not Allowed' for PUT, I think salesforce is not supporting PUT method on those url and gives the record updation feature through PATCH.

Comment: yeah, i am also thinking same one. anyway Thank you @Saumya Ranjan Satapathy